# Replacements: using condition to restrict to parts that satisfy a Boolean expression

Tags: replacement, conditional, expression-construction

I need to replace all integers k in a list with {k} and tried:

EDITED: as a clarification: I mean all integer *elements* of a list, not all integers in the list, so in the following example, only 4 should be replaced by {4}

```
(# /; AtomQ[#] -> {#} &) /@ {{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, 4}
```

which gives the result

```
{{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}} /; 
   AtomQ[{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}] -> {{{{1, 2}, {1, 
      3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}}, 4 /; AtomQ[4] -> {4}}
```

the command

```
(# -> {#}) & /@ {1, {2}}
```

works fine (i.e. encloses all elements in brackets). Replacements can be restricted via conditionals according to Mathematica documentation.

I am not clear on why

```
(# /; AtomQ[#] -> {#} &)
```

does not have the desired effect of enclosing 4 in brackets (in the example given at the outset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = {{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, 4};
```

You can also get the desired result by `Map`ping `List` on `expr` with level spec `{-1}`

```
Map[List, expr, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {{{{{1}, {2}}, {{1}, {3}}, {{2}, {3}}}, {{3}, {2}, {1}}}, {4}}
> ```

[`Level >> Details and Options`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Level.html):

[image]

```
Level[expr, {-1}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 4}
> ```

**Update:**

***"as a clarification: I mean all integer elements of a list, not all integers in the list, so in the following example, only 4 should be replaced by {4}"***:

You can use the replacement rule `x_?AtomQ :> {x}` (or  `x_ /; AtomQ[x] :> {x}`) and  level specification `1` in `Replace`:

```
Replace[
  {Sin[xx], 
   xx, 
   1 + xx, 
   {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, 
   {5}, 
   4}, 
  x_?AtomQ :> {x}, 
  1]
```

> ```
> {Sin[xx], 
>  {xx}, 
>  1 + xx, 
>  {{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, 
>  {5}, 
>  {4}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks, I was not sufficiently clear in the question. I added an edit to clarify the intent.

Comment: @Mike, please see the update.

Comment: Thanks, very clear.

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the following:

```
list = {{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, 4};

Replace[list, n_Integer :> {n}, 1]
Replace[list, n_?NumberQ :> {n}, 1]

(* Out: {{{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}, {3, 2, 1}}, {4}} *)
```

---

Your expression `(# /; AtomQ[#] -> {#} &)` is a function that generates (somewhat malformed) conditional rules; it is not "a function that gets applied conditionally", as you may have intended. See for instance the result of the following:

```
(# /; AtomQ[#] -> {#} &)@ 2

(* Out: 2 /; AtomQ[2] -> {2} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not sufficiently clear in the question. I added an edit to clarify the intent.

Comment: @Mike see edited version of my answer

Comment: Thanks, that works!